# Load a Image from SDCard to DrawingView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm a newbie for android development. I need some help with loading image from SDCard to a drawingView. What I'm trying to achieve here is after loading the image i want to modify the image and save.
So my primary task is to load the image to DrawingView. 
Appreciate your help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

please use something like this ..this worked for me

```
YourDrawingView jpgView = (YourDrawingView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/sample-1.jpg");
jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and here is my DrawingView

```
public class DrawingView extends ImageView {

    private boolean erase = false;
    //drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setUpDrawing();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private void setUpDrawing() {
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;

        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    }

    public void setErase(boolean isErase) {
        //set erase true or false
        erase = isErase;
        if (erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
    }

    public void setBrushSize(float newSize) {
        //update size
        float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        brushSize = pixelAmount;

        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);

    }

    public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize) {
        lastBrushSize = lastSize;
    }

    public float getLastBrushSize() {
        return lastBrushSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;


    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        invalidate();

        paintColor = Color.parseColor(color);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);

    }


    public void startNew() {
        drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vivek thanks for your response, cannot access setImageBitmap(bitmap) method. how can i solve it ?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention my custom view extended ImageView

Comment: No problem mate, May I see how you extended it from imageview?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is `DrawingView`, or do you mean `ImageView`?

```
File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/my_photo_1.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas to draw image, Below is code :

```
public class Keypaint extends View {
    Paint p;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

 public Keypaint(Context context) {
  super(context);

  File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/my_photo_1.jpg");
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
  }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        p=new Paint();

        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);
    }


}
```